# Make the program run with the computer startup VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, startup

I want to make my program run with the computer startup in VB.NET. I know there is a lot of codes about it but why some antivirus is detected these codes as a virus when people use my program, they will think the file is a virus and I will lose my reputation so please help me (any code you have or method please put it in a comment I will test it).

I use this code:

```
My.Computer.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", True).SetValue(Application.ProductName, Application.ExecutablePath)
```

Comment: Don't do it automatically, but ask your users if they want your program to start at windows startup

Comment: Also you can put a shortcut to your program in the folder pointed by the enum Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup and use Environment.GetFolderPath to retrieve this location on your users computer

Comment: Remember that many computers don't automatically log in a user when the computer first starts. There's no desktop right away. Even if you do have an account login automatically, it takes a few minutes for the system to get that far. With that in mind, it's often better to have your program run _when a user logs in_.

Comment: There is no *current user* when the computer starts up. You'll need to wait until the user logs in. Put a shortcut in the user's Startup folder instead. Trying to do it the wrong way around is why you're having issues with antivirus software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Steve describes the right way ,  you will not need to write any code. Just copy the .exe shortcut to the startup folder. This can be done by setup if your program has or by manually or your program can do at first runtime.

Use **Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup** to get the directory.

Paste shortcut there.